# Converting msi to msix : how to pass user inputs in msix format?

Tags: windows-installer, msix

I had converted msi file into msix using MSIX packaging tool. 
Now, how should i pass all the inputs which i used to provide/validate in msi installer screens?
I had already checked the msix file for any config file to provide inputs but no such file was there.

Comment: Didn't you already pass those when you converted the msi package to an MSIX? are you referring to customizing the installation, as you could do with MST files when installing your MSI?

Comment: yes. I did. But my inputs can vary for different user.e.g port, database server location,windows service credentials etc. How should i handle these variables?

Comment: For that you need to use a modification MSIX package, here are more details in my Ignite session (jumpstart to 3:45 if you don't have time for the entire session): https://myignite.techcommunity.microsoft.com/sessions/67612

Comment: @BogdanMitrache , sorry for replying late. I have gone through your session and others Ignite sessions too.My take away was its just capturing the changes made by msi install.How should then my custom actions going to run like executing dll, other scripts? I got the MSIX modification thing but its just give option to change what my app did system changes. My installer require database to be installed at remote location, how should i do that with MSIX now?

Comment: The discussion can get more complicated, but I tried to summarize the main subjects in my answer below. Hope it helps paint a better picture on what you can do with an MSIX package.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Differences between MSIX and MSI packages**, deployment wise.

1) Applying additional custom settings, like new registry or files, or modifying defaults from the original package can be done with **MSIX modification packages**. This is the equivalent of MST files applied to the MSI packages, but with some differences.

MSIX modification files properties:

- version free - i.e. you can install a new version of your app without rebuilding or redeploying the modification package (this was not possible with MST files)
- they install separately and behave as two separate packages which can be updated separately. You do not have to deploy the modification package at the same time with the main app, like you used to do for MSI and MST files.

2) **You don't have custom actions** in MSIX packages. All the resources (files, registry, configs, defaults) from the package must be included in the MSIX package you build so the app can run accordingly for the user.

If you require user input for certain configs, you will prompt the user [the first time the app is launch](https://www.advancedinstaller.com/msix-introduction.html#first-launch-configurations), not during the installation.

3) **MSIX packages can install only per-user**. [More details.](https://www.advancedinstaller.com/msix-introduction.html#per-user-deployment)

Basically, if you had an MSI/EXE that was setting up a database on some remote server/location, this is currently not possible with an MSIX package. You need to use a separate installer for deploying the database.